# BCP shift values in SQL Server with ID primary key

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using `bcp` to import a `.csv` file into a table in SQL Server like this:

```
bcp test1 in "./file.csv" -S server_name -U login_id -P password -d database_name -c -t
```

I get this message/warning:

> Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file.
>   bcp copy in failed

`file.csv` data:

```
A, B, C
A, B, C
A, B, C
A, B, C
```

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE test2
(
    a VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    b VARCHAR(8),
    c VARCHAR(8)
);

CREATE TABLE test1 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    a VARCHAR(8),
    b VARCHAR(8),
    c VARCHAR(8)

    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES test2(a)
);
```

Here is what I get in my `SELECT * FROM test1;`:

```
ID | a | b |   c   |
1    B   CA B    C
A    B   CA B    C
```

Here is what I expected:

```
ID|a |b |c
1  A  B  C
2  A  B  C
3  A  B  C
3  A  B  C
```

I'm having no issues with `test2` which is nearly like `test` but without `ID`. So the `csv` files are well formatted. So why do I have a shift like this?

**EDIT 1**

If I add header to `csv` fileI have this in my `SELECT * FROM test1`:

```
ID|a|b|c                        |
1  b cA B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C
```

**EDIT 2**

I generated a `File Format` to guide my data.

```
13.0
3
1    SQLCHQR    0    40    "\t"    1    a    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2    SQLCHQR    0    40    "\t"    2    a    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3    SQLCHQR    0    40    "\t"    3    a    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The modified one to try to "jump" over `ID`

```
13.0
4
1    SQLCHQR    0    40    "\t"    2    a    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2    SQLCHQR    0    40    "\t"    3    a    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3    SQLCHQR    0    40    "\t"    4    a    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

But I can't manage to make it work.

```
bcp test1 in "./file.csv" -S server_name -U login_id -P password -d database_name -f file_name -t
```

> SQLState = S1002, NativeError = 0 
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index

**EDIT 3**

I found a way around the problem, but it's still not the good solution. What I did is:
Change my `test1` table, putting `ID` column at the end.
Then adding with `sed` double commas at the end of each lines in my CSV to create a new empty column. Then I made a simple `bcp` `in`. I still want keep `ID` in first column, I just don't want to create an extra `View` for putting `ID` in front.

Comment: Try adding header to csv file

Comment: Made an update on post to see better the result.

Answer (score 1):

**First Edit** due to inverse meaning for the `-E` switch

You are missing missing the `-E` for the `BCP` to know that you are trying to use Identity column.

If you use this switch then the values are taken from the file and the SQL Server Identity value is ignored.  You should preform `DBCC CHECKIDENT('table_name', RESEED)` afterwards.

**Second Edit** due to the more specific user whishes.

After edit @BeGreen specified that he wants to use `format file`.  I'll post then the example how to do it.  No need for the view in front which I saw in other post on Stack overflow: [What will be BCP format for inserting a identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177439/what-will-be-bcp-format-for-inserting-a-identity-column#3177605).

The examples are being inconsistent in that CSV is mixing `","` (in the example) and `"\t"` (in the format table).  I'll be using only `","` in the examples.

That is possible but you have to use correct approach.

First you have to generate the format file by this command:

```
bcp <db_name>.dbo.test1 format nul -c -f "generated_format_file.fmt" -t "," -S "<server>\<instance>" -T
```

Then you take generated `.fmt` file in this case (using SQL Server 2005 - as I have quick testing instance there - you can change the first number to fit your needs e.g. 13.0):

```
8.0
4
1       SQLCHAR       0       12      ","                       1     ID     ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       8       ","                       2     a      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       8       ","                       3     b      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       8       "\r\n"                    4     c      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The `*.csv` file looks (I have added the ID for tests and different from the Identity values that should be inserted into the table):

```
10,A1,B1,C1
20,A2,B2,C2
30,A3,B3,C3
40,A4,B4,C4
```

Then the correct command for importing (note: using trusted connection `-T` instead of `-U` `-P` to make the line shorter):

```
bcp <db_name>.<schema>.test1 IN "import_data.bcp" -f "generated_format_file.fmt" -t "," -S "<server>\<instance>" -T

Starting copy...

4 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 218    Average : (18.35 rows per sec.)
```

Data is imported as (test1):

```
ID  a   b   c
1   A1  B1  C1
2   A2  B2  C2
3   A3  B3  C3
4   A4  B4  C4
```

To check identity value that is currently at test1:

```
select IDENT_CURRENT('[database_name].[dbo].[test1]')
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
4
```

Comment: I think `-E` does the inverse of what you are saying. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#E) It says:
`If -E is not given, the identity values for this column in the data file being imported are ignored, and SQL Server automatically assigns unique values based on the seed and increment values specified during table creation.`

Comment: Shouldn't I try to do a `File Format` to ignore `ID` column?

Comment: Yes you are right.  I'll edit the answer.  What I meant is that if you have the switch on you have to have your own ID values for the identity column.  Btw. do you have `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` or `OFF`?  You could do it in that way that you switch it ON do your bcp insert then switch it OFF and do `RESEED` (via `DBCC`) the identity.  You can add a ID column (with values like 10, 20, 30) which will get ignored to see if the insert works correctly for you (and use identity currently set for your table)

Comment: I'm tryig to use `File Format` seems easier. So I've generated a file with `-f`, but i can't manage to use it back. `bcp Table1 in "./file.csv" -S server_name -U login_id-P password -d databse_name -f format_file -t` but I get : `error invalid descriptor index`
`

Comment: @BeGreen see my edit.  All code has been tested on my SQL 2005 testing instance so it should work for your newest SQL Server.